# How to plot the SHAP values log loss with index as x-axis

Tags: python, shap

Trying to plot the shap-values of a given feature w.r.t log-loss and setting the x-axis to be the index.
as the attached image.

[image: Shap Values w.r.t log-loss]

While from the documentation only finding the `scatter` & `dependence` plot which are plotting x-axis the feature values not the index (as needed)

```py
shap.dependence_plot("feat_A", shap_lloss.values, X, interaction_index="feat_A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is called `monitoring_plot`

```py
shap.monitoring_plot(ind=0, 
                     shap_values=shap_lloss.values,
                     features=X,
                     )
```

[Documentation](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.monitoring_plot.html)